# IFrame scroll is not working in ios app through phonegap

Tags: cordova, ios6

I am trying to call a external url in ios app using html iframe through phonegap. I can able to view the site but i can't able to scroll it.

Answer (score 9):

warp your iframe in  as follow

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:scroll !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important">
  <iframe src="www.your_url.com" scrolling="yes" style="width:100%;height:100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: webkit-overflow-scrolling is what did it for me